# Getting warning while using nullable reference type with a generic type

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have a generic type like the following, with a method named `ExecuteAsync()` which can return an object or `null`:

```cs
public interface IStoredProcedure<Result, Schema>
    where Result : IBaseEntity
    where Schema : IBaseSchema
{
    Task<Result> ExecuteAsync(Schema model);
}

public class StoredProcedure<Result, Schema> : IStoredProcedure<Result, Schema>
    where Result : IBaseEntity
    where Schema : IBaseSchema
{
    public async Task<Result> ExecuteAsync(Schema model){
        //I use QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync of Dapper here, which returns an object or null
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I use this in my service as follows:

```cs
public interface IContentService
{
    Task<Content?> Get(API_Content_Get schema);
}

public class ContentService : IContentService
{
    private readonly IStoredProcedure<Content?, API_Content_Get> _api_Content_Get;

    public ContentService(IStoredProcedure<Content?, API_Content_Get> api_Content_Get)
    {
        _api_Content_Get = api_Content_Get;
    }

    public async Task<Content?> Get(API_Content_Get schema)
    {
        Content? result = await _api_Content_Get.ExecuteAsync(schema);
        return result;
    }
}
```

If I don't add the `?` in `ContentService` to show that the content can be `null`, I get this warning:

[image]

I couldn't find a way to show that the content can be `null`. I can write it as follows, and it gets no warning, but it then assumes that the result value is not `null`:

```cs
private readonly IStoredProcedure<Content, API_Content_Get> _api_Content_Get;
public ContentService(IStoredProcedure<Content, API_Content_Get> api_Content_Get)
{
    _api_Content_Get = api_Content_Get;
}

public async Task<Content?> Get(API_Content_Get schema)
{
    Content? result = await _api_Content_Get.ExecuteAsync(schema);
    return result;
}
```

I know that it's just a warning and doesn't affect the process. But is there anything that I can do to fix it?

I think it's a bug in this new feature that should be fixed.

Comment: The warning happens because you have `Content?` generic type argument. You can try to make interface declaration allowing nullable, something like that `IStoreProcedure<Result?, Schema>`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I tried but it gives error

Comment: Try converting `Content?` to `Content`

Comment: @Hadi Yes I can do it. But then what's the point of using nullable reference types if we ignore it whenever we want?

Comment: @Maddie Can you share the complete code sample, because I can't reproduce your problem

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski It's a big project I can't share the whole code. But I added some more lines to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is the syntax you're after:

```cs
public interface IStoreProcedure<Result, Schema>
where Result : IBaseEntity?
where Schema : IBaseSchema {
   Task<Result> ExecuteAsync(Schema model);
}
```

It seems that by default, in a nullable context, a type constraint implies non-nullability, so to get nullability you have to add `?` to the type constraint.

Comment: I don't want to show that it's "not null". It's the opposite. The return type can be null but it doesn't let me indicate that. So when I use it in other parts of my project, I can't use its return type as nullable.